# how to show div, if after every 5 seconds button not clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden div and i want to show div but i have a condition if after every 5 seconds button clicked then div not show, if after 5 seconds button not clicked then div show.

```
<div style="display: none;">You Fail.</div>
<button type="button" id="proceed">5 seconds click</button>
```

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: Seems you assigned a task to stackoverflow community :)

Comment: @Rajendra, if i understood you corectly , i guess you can use setTimeout() , so once the button clicked - count time and then execute what ever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

```js
let timeout;
document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = (e) => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  document.querySelector('#div').style.visibility = "hidden";
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('#div').style.visibility = "visible";
  }, 5000);
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<div id="div">Click the button again</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenContent" class="hidden">Some hidden content</div>

<button id="myButton">Click Here</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
(() => {

  const $hidden = document.getElementById('hiddenContent');
  const $myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
  let intervalId;

  const restartTimer = () => {
    $hidden.classList.add('hidden');
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      $hidden.classList.remove('hidden');
    }, 5000)
  };

  const cancelTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    restartTimer();
  };

  $myButton.addEventListener('click', cancelTimer);
  restartTimer();

})();
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0167L0ya/).